# Confusion of how to use twitter bootstrap less file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting mad over this confusion. I've installed twitter bootstrap through terminal then i install the gem file. After other small small formalities i've my bootstrap.less file in my assest pipeline. Now when i create a new view page and i want changes in the css so i just put those things in the newly created css.scss file in the assest pipeline. But after ive 2-3 css.scss files of different view files now i dont know why it is taking the definition of classes from different files.

For example
Ive one view file named as `home.html.erb` so the file of the same name is created in the assest pipeline named as `home.css.scss`. Now ive given some changes which i want only for this view page not for the other pages. 
Now i ve another view page named as `gallery.html.erb` so this file automatically taking definitions from the `home.css.scss`. i dont why this is happening? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). It creates a .scss for each controller you've created. And it imports automaticaly to your views. In production environment, they all merged in one single file (in normal conditions).

Please, read this [doc](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/24/asset-pipeline-for-dummies/) to understand how it works.